# ADB logcat: how to get application name?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

My phone is freezing and I'm trying to determine what application(s) are causing it.  When I see adb logcat's output online, it gives an application name but I don't appear to get that at all:

```
08-26 08:33:09.596  6547  6563 I art     : Starting a blocking GC NativeAlloc
08-26 08:33:09.596  6547  6563 I art     : Starting a blocking GC NativeAlloc
08-26 08:33:09.685 20256 20374 I art     : Starting a blocking GC NativeAlloc
08-26 08:33:09.685 20256 20374 I art     : Starting a blocking GC NativeAlloc
08-26 08:33:09.710  1736  2376 I art     : Starting a blocking GC NativeAlloc
08-26 08:33:09.710  1736  2376 I art     : Starting a blocking GC NativeAlloc
```

How do I either get logcat to display the application name or use the PID to get the application name?

Comment: The 3rd column is the `PID`

Comment: The 6th column is the app name

Comment: art is the app name?

Comment: `art` is the Android Run Time: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/

Answer (score -2):

`adb logcat` prints out the raw text from the device's log file. You cannot force it to print additional information because what you see is all there is. In the example you show, the app that is logging the output is called "art". This is the [Android Run Time](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/). The log entries you show tell us that the run time is doing some garbage collection. Whether or not that is the cause of your device hanging is difficult to tell. It also doesn't tell us why art is doing so much garbage collection or what app is eating up device memory that requires the GC to run.

Comment: I don't need to find my application, I need to figure out what process is causing my device to hang.

Comment: @DemiImp Okay, I understand your question better. I don't have a good answer for you, but I have a small explanation in my edited answer for you.